# Trouble calling the fileTree( Object, Closure ) signature

Tags: groovy, gradle

I have a method that takes a string and a closure, which I include in my plugin convention:

```
def someMethod( String obj, Closure closure) {
    println('HERE I AM')
    confFileTree = project.fileTree( obj, closure )
}
```

From a Junit test I call it like so:

```
project.convention.plugins.license.licenseFiles( 'src') {
    include "main/java/**"
    include "main/resources/*.properties"
    exclude "**/Licensed.java"
}
```

I know the method is called because 'HERE I AM' is printed.  But I then get an error that says:

```
org.gradle.api.internal.MissingMethodException: 
    Could not find method fileTree() for arguments 
    [src, nl.javadude.gradle.plugins.license.tasks.LicenseTaskTest$_shouldScanFilesForLicenseWithExclude_closure1@3cbdb6ae] 
    on root project 'test'.
```

I should state that this code originally just called the Closure form of fileTree, with "from 'src'" in the closure, which works fine, but Gradle milestone 8 is telling me that it is a deprecated method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the test is running against m8? In any case, here are a few suggestions for improvement (since I already know what you are trying to achieve):

- I don't think you want to construct your own file tree. You just want the user to pass a 'filter' closure (like in your example) which you then apply to the source directory set (e.g. `sourceSets.main.java`) with the `FileTree.matching(Closure)` method. You'll get back a new file tree with the filter applied.
- I recommend to use an extension rather than a convention object
- You don't need the long-winded syntax when accessing convention objects or extensions from Groovy code. In your unit test example, you can just say `project.licenseFiles(...) {...}`.

Comment: To your first bullet:  the source directory set contains only the things under src, right?  e.g. src/main/java and src/main/resources in the case of a java project.  e.g. A project I want to operate on has at least 4 other paths with original content that are siblings to the 'src' directory.  I can imagine providing configuration options that work either with SourceSets or FileTree though ).  I will double check I am on m8.  Why do you recommend an extension object rather than a convention object?

Comment: Projects are supposed to declare _all_ their sources via source sets. They can add as many source roots as they want to, say, `sourceSets.main.java`. Therefore I'd first concentrate on filtering an existing source set. Often, even the filtering won't be needed - by default the plugin should simply operate on all sources. It's probably good to add one task per source set, as this is the general convention in Gradle. Convention objects are the old mechanism. Extensions are better for almost all use cases, and they are the future.

Comment: It would seem I was not using m8, even though I had it configured so, see [STS-2458](https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-2458)